# using extension method for dropdown

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, extension-methods

I'm currently working on a MVC app which has a create and edit view. Both views are very similar in terms of the UI. On each page I've got around 5-7 dropdowns which I populate in the controller with the help of the following extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> textSelector, Func<T, string> valueSelector)
{
   return items.OrderBy(item => textSelector(item))
         .Select(item =>
         new SelectListItem
         {
           Text = textSelector(item),
           Value = valueSelector(item)
         });
}
```

Now on edit view I want to display the same dropdowns but this time with the selected value to be set to true to whatever the user selected on the create view. This is how I'm currently doing this

```
List<SelectListItem> userDdl = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var items in GetUserDropDown(userId, userName))
{
   userDdl.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = items.Value, Text = items.Text });
}

userDdl.Where(a => a.Value == someValueFromDb).First().Selected = true;
```

This works ine but I was thinking is there a better way approach for this or am I stuck with this

Comment: Check code review website which is also part of Stack Exchange ! http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mybirthname Thanks, shall I delete the question from here and add it there? Or is there a way to transfer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manage to figure something out. I created an overload for `ToSelectListItems` method as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T>(this List<T> items, Func<T, string> nameSelector, Func<T, string> valueSelector, Func<T, bool> selecter)
{
   return items
       .OrderBy(item => nameSelector(item))
       .Select(item =>
        new SelectListItem
        {
           Selected = selecter(item),
           Text = nameSelector(item),
           Value = valueSelector(item)
        });
}
```

Now I can do:

```
List<SelectListItem> userDdl = GetUserDropDown(userId, userName).ToSelectListItems(a => a.UserName, a => a.UserId.ToString(), a => a.UserId.ToString() == userIdFromDb).ToList();
```